# Banco de dados offline

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Estou criando um programa que use um banco de dados em arquivo. Me disseram que o SQLite serve pra isso, eu posso criar banco de dados com ele e acessar por arquivo. No caso então eu usaria a biblioteca SQL ou JDBC pra me conectar a esse banco de dados? O SQL já vem no Java ou eu tenho que baixar a biblioteca 'completa'?

Se eu tivesse criando uma aplicação que tem vários campos de texto, a pessoa escreve e ele grava esse texto. Eu quero guardá-lo em um banco de dados ao inveis de vários arquivos txt. eu usaria SQL ou JDBC (ou os dois)?

Comment: Apenas para apontar outras opções além do SQLite, existem vários bancos embarcados inteiramente escritos em Java e otimizados para trabalhar com JDBC. Dentre eles: [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/), [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html), [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) (que já vem com o JDK sobre o nome de JavaDB)

Answer (score 1):

Você ira utilizar JDBC

No link a seguir tem todo o how to

[JDBC - Java + SQLite](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_JDBC_using_SQLite)